# Interior of $\{(x,y) \mid 0<x^2 -y^2 \leq 1\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to find interior of the following set $$A = \{(x,y) \mid 0<x^2 -y^2 \leq 1\}$$

MY attempt:

I have drawn the following diagram.

[image]

I have found out two equations are $x^2 - y^2 = 0$ and $x^2 - y^2 = 1$. The first of these is a pair of diagonal lines through the origin that make $45$ degree angles with the coordinate axes, and the second is a hyperbola going through $(-1; 0)$ and $(1,0)$ with asymptotes given by the lines $x^2 - y^2 = 0$.

Using the figure I can conclude that $\text{Int } A = \{(x,y) \mid 0<x^2 -y^2 < 1\}$.

But how to prove? I have no idea. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $A^\star=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid0<x^2-y^2<1\}$ is an open set and $A^\star\subset A$. Therefore, $A^\star\subset\mathring A$.

Now, take $(x,y)\in A\setminus A^\star$. Then $x^2-y^2=1$. Then, if $r>0$,$$(x+r)^2-(y+r)^2=1+2r(x-y),$$and therefore $(x+r)^2-(y+r)^2>1$ if $r>0$ (when $x>y$ or $r<0$ (when $x<y$). So, every open ball $B_\varepsilon\bigl((x,y)\bigr)$ contains points from $A^\complement$, and so $(x,y)\notin\mathring A$. This shows that $\mathring A\subset A^\star$. Therefore, $A^\star=\mathring A$.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your answer.  I know a way which makes $\{(x,y) \mid 0<x^2 -y^2 < 1\}$ is an open set. I noticed that if we take the continuous map $f(x,y) =x^2- y^2$, then             
$ \{(x,y) \mid 0<x^2 -y^2 <1 \} = f^{-1} ((0,1})$, hence an open set.  But I do not want to use of it, because Munkres did not introduce it criteria for open set till now. Is this possible to say it open using the formal definition?

Comment: If $0<x^2-y^2<1$, then take $r>0$ such that $\|(a,b)-(x,y)\|<r\implies f(a,b)\in(0,1)$. Then $B_r\bigl((x,y)\bigr)\subset\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid0<x^2-y^2<1\}$.